# Simple(?) question about divisibility of polynomials based on roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, ideals

> Suppose $F$ a field and $A, B \subseteq F$ be finite subsets. Define $g(x) = \prod_{a \in A}(x- a)$ and $h(y) = \prod_{b \in B}(y - b)$. Then consider $f \in F[x, y]$ such that for every $(a, b) \in A \times B$ we have that $f(a, b) = 0$. Show that $f \in (g, h)$.

On the face of it this seems intuitive and obvious. But I'm somehow struggling with it. I think it's notational mostly. If it was just one variable $x$, and we have that $f(a) = 0$ for every $a \in A$ then I think it's fairly obvious that $g | f$ or $f = 0$. But when you add the second variable, I'm a tad confused how to make the argument work.

I hope it's not too silly of a question but I would appreciate help.

Comment: I don't recall seeing this ever! From 2-dimensional Lagrange interpolation we see that the ring $\Gamma$ of all functions $A\times B\to F$ is isomorphic to $F[x,y]/(g,h)$. $\Gamma$ is reduced, hence so is that quotient ring, hence the ideal is equal to its radical, when Hilbert's Nullstellensatz settles the matter. But this has a very strong feel of swatting a fly with a cannonball, don't you think :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: A bit, yes. :p Especially since this question wasn't asked in the context of Nullstellenstatz or Lagrange Interpolation, etc. The 'pre-reqs' for this afaik are just basic ring theory, polynomial division, grobner bases, syzygy's, etc.

Comment: @KReiser I appreciate the sentiment, but I really want to find an elementary way :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if you're interested, I've posted an elementary approach below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary approach. By subtracting off multiples of $g$ and $h$, we may assume that $f$ is of degree less than $|A|$ in $x$ and less than $|B|$ in $y$. Writing $f = \sum_{i=0}^{|A|} p_i(y)x^i$, we see that if $f(x,b)\neq 0$, it cannot vanish at all elements in $A\times\{b\}$ for any fixed $b\in B$ because its degree is too low. Therefore $f(x,b)=0$ for all $b\in B$. But this means $p_i(b)=0$ for any $b\in B$, and every $p_i$ is of degree less than $|B|$, so each $p_i$ is actually zero as well and therefore $f\in (g,h)$.

Comment: Thanks :-) ${}{}$

Comment: Need a bit of clarification- so if $f$ has degree $<|A|$ in $x$ and $<|B|$ in y, then $f = 0$- I get that. But if the degrees are greater- how do we formalize "subtracting off" multiples of $f$ and $g$ exactly, and how do we show that the remainder can't be $0$. Basically, how do we deal with the case that the degrees are $>|A|$ and $>|B|$, if you don't mind?

Comment: Write $f=g\cdot f_1+h\cdot f_2 + f_3$ where $f_3$ fulfills the degree conditions. Since $g$ and $h$ are monic, we can always do this, and it's basically the division algorithm.